# How do proxy providers have such a massive amount of IPs?

Tags: proxy, ipv4

I was looking at a proxy provider this evening and it said:

> Our IPv4 database consists of over 500,000 IP addresses from all 6 major continents with 50 Mbps to 10 Gbps bandwidth.

I'm just wondering, how do these proxy providers get such a huge amount of IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proxy provider is just a kind of ISP. They can just request addresses from the relevant RIRs (ARIN, RIPE NCC etc). If they need 500.000 addresses, they get them.

Of course these days the RIRs don't have any IPv4 addresses anymore, but before they ran out it was just "show that you need them, and you get them".

This is also how it works for IPv6, of which there is plenty.

Comment: That makes sense. So, entering the market as a proxy provider nowadays must be nearly impossible, unless you're providing ipv6 IP addresses.

Comment: Indeed, unless you have a few million to spare to buy that many IPv4 addresses from someone else.